# get the text value of data-id element via selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I wonder if it is possible to see the "data-id" element of tag elements in Python via Selenium as a class, id, or name.
What I mean is that the data I want is covered inside div element as underlined in picture, within the span and anchor elements with the same data-id="nba:schedule:main:team:link" attribute
.
[image]

With code `driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//a[@data-id='nba:schedule:main:team:link']")` it sees only anchor elements. I wonder if there is a code to wrap up both data inside span and anchor elements only with single iteration like `driver.find_elements(By.ID,"nba:schedule:main:team:link")` or `(By.XPATH,"//div//[@data-id='nba:schedule:main...']"`

Whole code is below;

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from datetime import datetime
#import pandas as pd
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\chromedriver_win32 (1)\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.nba.com/schedule?pd=false&region=1")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
element_to_click=driver.find_element(By.ID,"onetrust-accept-btn-handler") #.click()
element_to_click.click()
element_to_save=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div/div/div/div/h4")

f=open(r'C:\pythonPro\t_bot\new_test.txt','r+')
f.write(element_to_save.text)
f.write("\n")
f.write(str(datetime.today()))
myList=[]


elements_to_save=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//a[@data-id='nba:schedule:main:team:link']")
for element in elements_to_save:
    f.write(element.text)
    myList.append(element.text)
    f.write(" \n ")
    f.write(str(datetime.today()))
    f.write("  ")

elements_to_save=driver.find_elements(By.ID,"nba:schedule:main:team:link")
for element in elements_to_save:
    f.write(" ")
    f.write(element.text)
    f.write(" \n ")
    f.write(str(datetime.today()))

f.close()
f=open(r'C:\pythonPro\t_bot\new_test.txt','r+')
print(f.read())
f.close()
time.sleep(3)
driver.get("https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/traditional")
print(myList)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both `a` and `span` elements there having the same `id` attribute value you can simple omit the tag name to match **any** tag element with the specified `id` attribute value, as following:

```py
elements_to_save=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//*[@data-id='nba:schedule:main:team:link']")
```

Comment: Did I understand correctly what you asked about?

Comment: Yes, you did. But let me check again, because it does not seem like it takes the values of both span and anchor elements. I will come back with result

Comment: This will return you all the elements with id = `nba:schedule:main:team:link`

Comment: Yeap, it does!)

Comment: Your answer works well. What you did is just replaced "a" attribute from code with "*". So interesting, I tried without "a", but gave me error. Good to know. Thanks!

Comment: Right. `*` means **any**. element with any tag name. You can not leave that position just blank. Need to mention some specific tag name like a, div, span etc or * for `any`